# Modify ssis package directly in the catalog

Tags: ssis

is there a way to directly modify a package in the ssis catalog?

What I'm trying to achieve is "source control" building something like a main repository for me and all other developers. We need more  visibility on the packages being built. i.e., when you pull into your own machines and not keep the development on the server, we don’t see what is being done.

Comment: How would the ability to modify a package directly in the catalog lead to/prevent packages from being under source control?

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered or editing it should you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use version control such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx) / [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx). Using the deployed package as version control is bad practice and might risk breaking it or making it unrecoverable.

Use a VCS, git and VSTS are free.

Comment: We use svn for this. I highly agree that using source control of whatever type is necessary for SSIS packages and any associated sql code you write for them such as stored procs, table creation scripts, function scripts, etc. We even source control our scripts to create jobs on the server. Of course this goes for all database code not just SSIS.